# Why did she suddenly turn on the agency?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, white-house-down

In the movie *[White House Down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_House_Down)* (2013), we know that a bomb is on its way to blow up the White House. During this time, in one agency, they call an opposing operative via laptop.

One woman said that she would be able to convince or get answers out of the terrorism operator  by calling them on the laptop computer, but she turns suddenly against the agency and yells all this stuff so the operative could hear.

She was with the agency all along until then. Some agents grabbed her and pulled her away into a room (or rooms) with glass covering.

***Why did she turn on the agency like that when she was an agent in the first place?***

*I may be mistaken in some descriptions

Comment: Wait up, ill edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sup>Your description does not quite match the action but there is one scene that is *partially* as you describe.</sup>

---

### The woman isn't an agent...she's Walker's (the ringleader) wife.

She reveals to the authorities that Walker has brain cancer which explains, partially, his actions.

However, when Walker tells her he's doing it because of his son, Kevin, she understands his motivations and refuses to help talk him down.

> They have to pay for what they did to Kevin. And when it's over......I promise...I promise you'll understand.
>
> You're doing this for Kevin?
>
> I swear to God.
>
> Then you do whatever it takes. You make them pay for what they did to our boy.

There's a section while the President and Cale are on the run inside the White House (actually on top of an elevator) when the President explains that Kevin was part of a team sent to Iran to investigate a nuclear threat. Something went wrong and Kevin was killed.

> The Pentagon thought that Iran had a nuclear bomb. We sent a team in.
> Things went wrong. Martin's son Kevin got killed.